# this(<params>) as shortcut in constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, this

I got a task that I need to reduce code in the constructor but when I do as in a given example it doesn't work :(

The source code looks so:

```
public class Item {
    private Product product;
    private int stock;

    Item(Product product){
        this.product=product;
        this.stock=0;
    }

    Item(Product product, int stock){
        this.product=product;
        this.stock=stock;
    }
```

I tried to write it in this way:

```
    public class Item {
        private Product product;
        private int stock;

        Item(Product product){
            this(product, 0);
        }

        Item(Product product, int stock){
            this(product, stock);
        }
```

Could somebody tell me please what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There's a circular reference in the second constructor, it's calling itself. Try this instead:

```
// this constructor is correctly defined
public Item(Product product, int stock) {
    this.product = product;
    this.stock   = stock;
}

// this constructor calls the other one
public Item(Product product) {
    this(product, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor is attempting to call itself, which makes no sense.

If your class had a super class having a constructor with the same parameters, you could write :

```
    Item(Product product, int stock){
        super(product,stock);
    }
```

Since it doesn't, you should just assign the members of the instance in the second constructor :

```
    Item(Product product, int stock){
        this.product = product;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
```